# How can I access files on home computer which were made on work computer?

Tags: python, git, sync, github

I am working on a group project on two computers (work computer and home computer). This group project has directory on github. Directory can be accessed by other group members. Directory is cloned on home and work computer under the same name. In this directory I have my folder in which I daily update my work (others have access to this) with git commands. Now in folder I have multiple files and I only push to github files that others can see. And other files I leave locally on my work computer in same folder. If I want to access files from home computer I have only access to files which were pushed on github from work computer. Now how can I access those files on home computer which I did not push on github from work computer? I want these files to appear localy on my home computer and that others can not see those files. I want to operate exclusively with github and git, not dropbox, flash drives and mailing ... Should I do another repository just for me and push those file there or it can be done differently ?

Comment: `Now how can I access those files on home computer which I did not push on github from work computer?` .. you change your workflow.  I myself would simply use a USB stick I carry back and forth.. but if you want to use git, use a git branch or git [sub-modules](https://www.taniarascia.com/git-submodules-private-content/) to store your "only you" files and push everything (but junk) up to the repository.  If you want them in the same dir, you will need to use a branch.  If you don't care, git sub-modules would probably be optimal.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas If I use branch, I have to push it from work computer to github that I will be able to see those junk files on my home computer. And this junk files will not been seen by others ? Is there any option in VSCode to sync those files (both useful and junk) because I am using VSCode on both computers ? Maybe this branching is little complicated.

Comment: files that aren't part of your git repository really should be kept outside the git repo directory. then you could use another repo, or a synch tool like onedrive/dropbox/whatever.

Comment: @FrankThomas .. using sub-modules *would be* using another repo (technically).  Am I wrong?

Comment: Right, a sub-module is a method for linking another repository to a subdirectory of your main repo. if op can separate the files into a new repo, and still has reason to link them into the main projects file structure, its a great idea.